# SQL or NoSQL for my app

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, nginx, nosql

I'm developing an application for iOS, Android, Windows Phone and in the future a web version of it.
I'm relatively new in databases so I started learning a bit of SQL and PostgreSQL.
My application is for industry and will show pruducts and other information relatively with that.
My question is should I use SQL database or NoSQL database, and which should I use?
Thanks!

Comment: I personally would use SQL until I need a reason to use NoSQL.  Does your use case fall into the four main categories of NoSQL usage:   http://rebelic.nl/2011/05/28/the-four-categories-of-nosql-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the database that makes it easiest to model your data. If your data is relational, use a relational database. If your data is best represented as a document, use a document database. If your data is best represented as a graph, use a graph database.

Comment: In the start I will have 3 relational tables, but NoSQL seems more easy, cheaper and faster but I don't know :/